# Can Not download PDF (LaTeX Version) in TEI-Publisher application

Tags: exist-db, tei, tei-publisher

When I try to download a PDF document (Latex Version) in my tei-publisher application the following error is returned:

```json
{
  "details" : null,
  "description" : "Cannot run program \"/usr/local/texlive/2020/bin/x86_64-darwin/pdflatex\" (in directory \"/tmp\"): error=2, No such file or directory. An IO error occurred while executing the process /usr/local/texlive/2020/bin/x86_64-darwin/pdflatex: Cannot run program \"/usr/local/texlive/2020/bin/x86_64-darwin/pdflatex\" (in directory \"/tmp\"): error=2, No such file or directory [at line 179 of unknown]"
}
```

Comment: Hi Yasir! Can you provide more context to your issue? Which version of TEI publisher are you using. Have you changed your configuration perhaps?

Comment: If you share which version of existdb you are running on which operating systems that would also increase the chance that people can help you.

Comment: The issue has been resolved.